# Save a multi-line string to a text file on multiple lines

Tags: c#

I have this bit of code below which saves perfectly fine to a text file, however there is no formatting that is transferred, for example, The below words would save as `THISISATESTLAYOUT`. I would like the desired output displayed below:

```
THIS
IS 
A
TEST
LAYOUT
```

I know there's something obvious im missing here so thanks for any help

```
        if (entity.Switch == true)
        {
            string path = @"filepath....\\Test.txt";
            if (!File.Exists(path))
            {
                // Create a file to write to. 
                using (StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText(path))
                {
                    sw.Write(entity.comments);
                }
            }
         }
```

this string is saved in one entity called **comments** and displays fine within the C# application.

`sw.Write` and `sw.WriteLine` both give the same single line output with no spaces

and also entity.comments references a column in an SQL Server Table, and is a VARCHAR(MAX)

Comment: What is the value of `entity.comments`? How do you determine there's no newlines in the output?

Comment: entity.comments is the same as a string comments would be, its called entity due using Lightswitch. and the value of comments is the example im giving above

Comment: Which example of the two you show? I mean does `entity.comments` already contain newlines, and if so, in which format?

Comment: entity.comments references an SQL Server table and comments is a varchar(MAX)

Comment: It's like newline are coded in unix style. Replace '\n' and \'r' by `Environment.NewLine`.

Comment: if you don't have your answer accepted or do not know an answer, marking a question down is not needed....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you may be using '\n' for newlines. If so use

```
sw.Write(entity.comments.Replace("\n", "\r\n"));
```

Comment: i have to wait till it lets me, 50 seconds;)

Comment: `Environment.NewLine` will be better than `"\r\n"`

Answer (score -1):

Change `sw.Write` to `sw.WriteLine`

Comment: this has the exact same affect as described above

Comment: Are you sure? You have compared the outputs from `Write` and `WriteLine` and they were exactly the same?

Comment: yes, the text itself is stored in a SQL Server Database and comments itself is a VARCHAR(MAX) so there seems to be a formatting issue when transferring that data displayed on the screen to a text file